# Angular 9 datatables

Tags: angular, angular-6, angular-material

Boa tarde, estou utilizando o datatable do link abaixo:
https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome
O único problema é atualizar o valor do grid após o update, segue imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Muito Obrigado.

Comment: Olá Jeff. É importante você [edit] sua pergunta [evitando imagens para demonstrar códigos por uma série de ótimos motivos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7817/3635) e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, **acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema** (essa é a parte mais importante). Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045). Obrigado por compreender.

Comment: Boa noite, desculpe sou novo no fórum, mas acredito que fui o mais especifico possível, mas gostaria de entender aonde eu errei. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Por favor leia os links, estão explicando como criar um exemplo minimo/simples e reproduzivel. Depois de ler você vai entender melhor como pode melhorar suas postagens. Grato pela compreensão.